# Entity Framework not returning data for few entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern, breeze, dbcontext

I am using repository pattern in mvc web api. The Dbcontext class is not returning any data for few entities while it fetches all the rows for other entities.
I am using breeze on client side. When the repository method is called from client side using a breeze query, data is returned.
When I am trying to unit test the controller method, I find that the context class does not return any data.

```
[Table("QaItemGrouping")]
public class QaItemGrouping
{
    [Key]
    public int QaItemGroupingCd { get; set; }

    public string QaItemGroupingDesc { get; set; }

    public ICollection<QaItem> QaItems { get; set; }
}
```

Above is the model class for the entity.

The Dbcontext class contains the property below:

```
public DbSet<QaItemGrouping> QaItemGroupings { get; set; }
```

The Repository class has the method below:

```
public DbQuery<QaItemGrouping> QaItemGroupings
{
   get { return (DbQuery<QaItemGrouping>)Context.QaItemGroupings; }
}
```

The method in controller class:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<QaItemGrouping> QaItemGroupings()
{
    return Repository.QaItemGroupings;
}
```

Comment: we can also simply wonder if you are not going to provide more details.

Comment: I have added little code. Let me know what more details do you want ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this only a problem with unit testing? You shouldn't be using live data for unit testing anyways. If you're relying on a database in your unit test, you're *not* unit testing: you're integration testing, which is a whole other can of worms.

The correct procedure here is to use a mocking framework to fake a result set that you can test against.

Answer (score 1):

I usually get around this by wrapping the generated data context with a wrapper.

Yes, Chris Pratt is correct. The whole point of mocking is to test the class only, without external data input.

Here are the rules to live by for unit testable (mockable) code:

- Use interface base programming.
- Use lazy loading or constructor injection of objects.
- Use the 'Has a' instead of 'Is a' philosophy.
- Use a factory to create objects or a third party IOC framework.

Comment: I agree with all of you regarding unit testing. But the dbcontext class should bring data for the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you might have missed your app.config in the test project. Please copy your web.config contents to that app.config. That should make them work.

Comment: But there are other methods in the same class of the test project that is returning data.

Comment: Actually, this worked for me. I just copied and pasted my web.config into my app.config. Working great now.

Comment: Wow that's great.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party on this but want to offer a WAG as I have seen the same thing.  Possibly Breeze is camel casing the JSON and this is making some of the entities look like they are not coming back.